# Measuring Response Times In Combination With WatiN

Tags: watin

I'm looking for a tool that I could potentially use in combination with [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) that would allow me to more or less measure both the response time of an interaction and also the filesize of the same interaction in combination with WatiN. Let's say, I make a google request. That's great, we've all seen that example, but what if I want to see how long that request took and also what was downloaded and how long it took. Does anyone know any tools that can be used programmatically to do this? Sure, there are many tools such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) that allow you to do this via an interface, but I'd like to be able to automatically generate reports and the like based on this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/): 
"HttpWatch is an HTTP viewer and debugger that integrates with IE and Firefox to provide seamless HTTP and HTTPS monitoring without leaving the browser window." 
There is an article on the website called [Using HttpWatch with WatiN](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/30/using-httpwatch-with-watin/) with sample code for using it with WatiN.